# Skip Pending and Skipped tests from HTML report in Cypress

Tags: cucumber, cypress, bdd, allure, mochawesome

I have written some BDD tests in **cypress** using **cucumber** and using below command to run my automation tests:

```js
./node_modules/.bin/cypress-tags run -e TAGS='not @ignore and @bdd',allure=true test:all
```

As I have **1** tests with **@bdd** tag so it runs it and shows other **3** tests from feature file as **Pending**

[image]

As I have integration with **mochawesome** and **allure** both shows Pending tests in corresponding HTML report as well.

[image]

Is there any way to skip|remove these tests (**Pending** and **Skipped**) from HTML reports

Here is my **mochawesome** config

[image]

Comment: could you add your config for mochawesome?

Comment: Yeah sure, Updated!

Answer (score 0):

By default, `mochawesome` should not show skipped tests in the html report. You can update your config as below.

```json
    showPending: false
    showSkipped: false
```

You can find all other flags supported in [this](https://github.com/adamgruber/mochawesome-report-generator#cli-flags) guide. A sample can be found [here](https://github.com/LironEr/cypress-mochawesome-reporter#custom-options).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @raju, making both of them **false** in config just does not show those tests entry in **mochawesome** HTML report but still it calculates shows chart **suite--chart-slice** with Pending tests as well, I would like to remove it completely.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see a way to get it done at this moment. Maybe you can raise a query in the respective repo for them to consider this as a feature.

Answer (score 0):

The `on('after:run')` hook can be used to modify the stats displayed in the header, including the chart.

It's not perfect but may suit your requirement.

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');
const { beforeRunHook, afterRunHook } = require('cypress-mochawesome-reporter/lib');
const { removePendingSkipped } = require('./remove-pending-skipped-from-report');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  reporter: 'cypress-mochawesome-reporter',
  reporterOptions: {
    reportDir: 'test-report',
    ...   // other options
  },
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('before:run', async (details) => {
        await beforeRunHook(details);
      });
      on('after:run', async () => {
        removePendingSkipped(config)
        await afterRunHook();
      });
    },
  },
});
```

**remove-pending-skipped-from-report.js**

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs-extra')

function removePendingSkipped(config) {
  const jsonPath = path.join(config.reporterOptions.reportDir , '/.jsons', '\mochawesome.json');
  const report = fs.readJsonSync(jsonPath)
  const topSuite = report.results[0].suites[0]
  remove(topSuite)
  fs.writeJsonSync(jsonPath, report)
}

function remove(suite, level = 0) {
  const childSuites = suite.suites.map(child => remove(child, ++level))
  suite.pending = []
  suite.skipped = []
  return suite
}

module.exports = {
  removePendingSkipped
}
```